# D3: selecting a <g> in an SVG does not work in Safari

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, safari, selection

I am trying to :

1. Load an external SVG
2. Select groups within that SVG to do something

This is a code snippet:

```
d3.xml("/img/Cell.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml")
  .get(function (error, documentFragment) {

    if (error) throw error;

    var svgNode = documentFragment.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
    document.body.appendChild(svgNode);

    d3.select("g#ID_of_G"); // returns an empty selection in Safari, works in Chrome and Firefox
   ...
});
```

I have also tried to change the selection to `d3.select("svg").select("g#ID_of_G")` but that did not change anything.

Comment: report it as a webkit bug to their bugtracker perhaps

Comment: For those looking to reproduce the issue, here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lkP4gmvGQRKzW7s6KdOC?p=preview), unfortunately I don't own a Mac so I can be no further help...

Comment: That code works for me in safari v10.0.2.  What version are you using?

Comment: Hi all. Many thanks for your replies. I am using Safari v9.0.2 but that should not be the issue. I have created a simple example here to show you my error:  http://152.83.245.51:8060/

Safari returns an empty selection. Maybe this is an issue with the way I embed my SVG? Or maybe it is an issue with my SVG?

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, ok, I found the problem:

Safari has an issue if the g-elements have IDs that have an **uppercase letter** in them. So I had to change the ID of the g-element from *ID_of_G* to *id_of_g* and select it using:

`d3.select("g#id_of_g");`

This bug report helped me find the solution: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83438